# How to pass values for translation file to ngfor in angular8

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I have some text in my translation (json) file which I'd like to pass through an `*ngFor` in my component.

I like to replace that code with the `*ngFor*`:

```
  <div class="container padding-top-3">
      <div class="segmented-controls-group">
        <span class="filter__intro">
          <i class="icon icon-253-filter icon--s2" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{'COMMONS.TAG.FILTER'|translate}}
        </span>
        <input type="radio" id="segmented-controls1-1" class="tag">
        <label for="segmented-controls1-1" tabindex="0">Marketing</label>
        <input type="radio" id="segmented-controls1-2" class="tag">
        <label for="segmented-controls1-2" tabindex="0">TV</label>
        <input type="radio" id="segmented-controls1-3" class="tag">
        <label for="segmented-controls1-3" tabindex="0">Sponsoring</label>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Could anyone support me?

Comment: What does your json look like? Have you tried anything yet? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.Parse(json) to transform your **json** to an **object**

And then iterate in it like any array

```
public jsonToObject(string json): any{
    return JSON.Parse(json);
}
```

This will work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let key of ['MARKETING', 'TV', 'SPONSORING']; let i = index">
  <input  type="radio" [attr.id]="'segmented-controls1-' + i" class="tag" name="tag">
  <label [attr.for]="'segmented-controls1-' + i" tabindex="0">
   {{('COMMONS.TAG.' + key) | translate}}
  </label>
</ng-container>
```